# Props undefined. Data is fetched but not passed as props using getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, getserversideprops

I'm trying to learn nextjs. Struggling to work out routing with getServerSideProps.
I am trying to build a pizza restaurant website. I have build my own API.

The data is successfully fetched from the API but it is not passed as props to HOME function.
When I logged props in console it is showing undefined.

I am using version 9 of next.js

```
        import Head from 'next/head';
        import Image from 'next/image';
        import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
        import Slider from '../Components/Slider';
        import PizzaList from '../Components/PizzaList';
        import axios from 'axios';


        function Home({ pizzaList }) {
          console.log("pizzaList prop:", pizzaList);
          return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
              <Head>
                <title>Pizza Restaurant</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
              </Head>
              <Slider />
              <PizzaList pizzaList={pizzaList} />
            </div>
          )
        }

        export async function getServerSideProps() {

          const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/Products");
          const pizzaList = res.data;
          console.log(pizzaList);
          return { props: { pizzaList } }
        }


        export default Home
```

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjpdR.png)